# Authorization header for Kinesis Proxy AWS API Gateway with a custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

Given a [Kinesis proxy API using API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html) and a custom domain (http://mycustomkinesis.foo.com/stream/events) added to access the API, how do I send the authorization header in HTTP POST request to the above URI?
I was able to test the API using API Key header. But I want to enable AWS_IAM for authentication. When I call the API from http rest clients, how do I compute auth header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway uses standard [Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) for signing. Regardless of whether you are using custom domains or not the service name portion of the derived key will be **execute-api** and the region will be the region of your API Gateway API.

If you are using Javascript, iOS or Android, API Gateway provides [generated SDKs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html) that will handle this for you, but does require some additional work to model your API. Other AWS SDKs (such as PHP) offer [generic signers](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/671#issuecomment-120666137) that can be leveraged to sign your requests before sending to your API Gateway API.